# Asynchronous image downloader for blackberry

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, asynchronous, java-me

I have a need of creating a image gallery. The images are saved in the remote server. The Blackberry client need to download and render it to the UI (Gallery View).

I have used "UniversalImageDownloaer" library for android. But now for I am looking for any such freeware/open source lib that will help me to serve my purpose for BlackBerry. Can Anyone help me guiding me to a resource.

I need to look into the following things

1. Async image download
2. Gallery view
3. Image caching

**Edit-1**
From my earlier experience, I understand that Blackberry has the restriction for creating maximum of 250 (Many be 5+/-) number of threads at run time. And per application it is restricted to 17 number of threads. So I must look into the thread pool and thread safety for my requirements.

Comment: Just a comment.  There's no reason for you to even want to use more than 17 threads for this purpose, even if you have many more than 17 images to download.  Running multiple network requests in parallel doesn't make them go faster.  If some of the images are on different servers, it may be useful to have more than one worker thread, so that if one server is down (or slow), it doesn't block the progress of downloads from other servers.  But, you wouldn't really benefit from 17 worker threads.  So, this isn't much of a limitation in almost all situations.

Comment: @Nate. I didn't mean to create 17 worker threads. I just shared my thought.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any library for lazy loading in BB. You could try to port that library to BlackBerry, or DIY. Let's see how could you achieve this:

1. You can code a consumer thread, which will download an image at a time (in Blackberry, you won't get much performance improvement downloading in parallel). This consumer could take URLs from a stack. The UI (screen, list) will submit a request to the consumer each time it needs an image. The request is just passing the resource URL to the consumer, so that it puts it at the top of the stack. In the meantime, the GUI should display a default image or loading message. There are plenty of good books and manuals in Java on how to design a consumer-producer scheme in a thread-safe manner, but it goes beyond the scope of this answer.
2. Starting in OS 5.0, you have the [PictureScrollField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/extension/component/PictureScrollField.html) class that allows you to display a row of scrolling images, and can be customized to some extent. There's a sample demo app in the samples folder in the SDK, I think.
3. If multiple requests to the same image are likely to be made during the program execution, caching is an interesting enhancement. You could just keep them in RAM in the consumer stack, or even save them to a folder in SDCard. the consumer will then look first in the cache, and only in case it doesn't exist will it initiate a remote download.